# How to get a single Interactive Correlation scatterplot matrix triangle with R ggpairs and plotly

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot, ggplotly, ggally

I am attempting to get an interactive scatterplot matrix for ~5 variables I am interested in seeing how the observations of each correlate with each other, and to spot and identify outliers. The problem is that `plotly` is behaving unpredictably, in my opinion.

```
#sample data    
sample_data <- data.frame(Class = sample(x= letters[1:15],size=50,replace = TRUE),
                      Sample_number = seq(1,50,by=1),
                        x1= rnorm(50,mean=0, sd=.5), 
                        x2= rnorm(50,mean=0.5, sd=1.5), 
                        x3= rnorm(50,mean=5, sd=.1), 
                        x4= rnorm(50,mean=0, sd=3.5),
                        x5= rnorm(50,mean=-6, sd=.005))

#creating the standard plot    
p1 <- ggpairs(data=sample_data, # data.frame with variables
          columns=3:7, # columns to plot, default to all.
          title=paste0("Variable Correlations"), # title of the plot
          aes(color = Class, text=Sample_number), 
          progress = FALSE) +
          theme_bw()

#creating the interactive plot
ggplotly(p1)
```

## Example 1

The matrix with both triangles looks like this [image] I get the following warnings

```
Warning messages:
1: Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped. 
2: Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped. 
3: Can only have one: highlight
```

## Example 2

However, when I change to only view one triangle of the matrix this is what it gives me, with the same warnings as above:

```
p2 <- ggpairs(data=sample_data, # data.frame with variables
              columns=3:7, # columns to plot, default to all.
              title=paste0("Variable Correlations"), # title of the plot
              aes(color = Class, text=Sample_number), 
              uppper=list(continuous="points"),
              lower="blank", 
              progress = FALSE)+
  theme_bw()

ggplotly(p2)
```

[image]

## Objective

But if I were to use only the standard (non-interactive) `ggpairs` output it looks pretty nice:[image] This time I only get the `Warning messages: 1: Groups with fewer than two data points have been dropped.`It would be awesome if someone had any ideas on how to make a `ploty` subplot just as the standard `ggpairs` example so to enable the interactivity.